# Can someone explain the function of margins=True argument in pandas.pivot_table function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset that has tipping information for certain number of parties held on week days. When using pivot_table function on this dataset (I get that we're grouping by 'time' and 'day' and applying default function DataFrameGroupBy.mean to every group), when I pass margins = True as an argument, I get an output that looks something like this.

Dataset: tips

[DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LLzc.png)

Performing data aggregation using below code snippet:
tips.pivot_table(['tip_pct','size'],index=['time','day'],  columns = ['smoker'],margins=True)

I get an output like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgOwO.png)

I want to know how does margins = True work here, which rows or columns are added to get the repective value at each cell under 'All'.

Appreciate your help!

Not able to understand the 'how' of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas
margins = True will give you the mean(average) of each column and row independently in a DataFrame
It will ignore sum_totals

leave out (..., margins = True) and use

(..., aggfunc = sum)  # will give you the sum

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).